# How to add content to header after include?

Tags: php, class

i need to archive somthing like that with that 2 files:

file 1: header.php

```
<!doctype>
....
<title>$title</title>
...
```

file 2: body.php

```
include("header.php");
$title = "Hello! My tittle"
```

**So what i want is:**

result : include() + body()

```
<!doctype>
....
<title>Hello! My tittle</title>
...
```

**but** i get:

```
<!doctype>
....
<title></title>
...
```

how can i do this? is it possible? Thanks

Comment: once you include a file, it is parsed and run at that time. Setting a variable after the include wouldn't have any effect because the script has already run. Couldn't you just set the variable before including the file?

Comment: @BrainStack: Well yeah I bet you can

Comment: Then your only other option would be to make it like a template system. Capture the output from the include and afterwards do something like `str_replace('<title></title>', '<title>'.$title.'</title>')`.

Comment: MY FACE IS LIKE( ಠ益ಠ) YES, i can set the variable before including...

Comment: Thanks @JonathanKuhn in near future i will do somthing like you said ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reversing the order. Set the `$title` before the include.

```
$title = "Hello! My tittle";
include("header.php");
```

Comment: Thanks ... please dont say it to my mom xD